# Where am I getting the 'Mean of Empty Slice' error and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, warnings, mean

I've got a python program that runs the K-Means algorithm on a set of data. It is for a homework assignment. It has to be built without using the built in kmeans function from `sclearn`.

Basically, I set a value for `qty` and that sets the amount of centroids/clusters. It then creates random x and y points to use as my clusters. Sometimes it runs without error, and other times it give me this:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 59
    warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 68
    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
import random
import sys

dataPoints = np.array([[2,4],[17,4],[45,2],[45,7],[16,32],[32,14],[20,56],[68,33],[54,36],[3,54],[23,5],[56,23],[10,81],[64,15],[23,18],[22,15],[35,19],[66,19],[1,99]])

rangeX = (0, 100)
rangeY = (0, 100)
qty = 5 

randomCentroids = []
i = 0
while i<qty:
    x = random.randrange(*rangeX)
    y = random.randrange(*rangeY)
    randomCentroids.append((x,y))
    i += 1
centroids = np.asarray(randomCentroids)

def size(vector):
    return np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in vector))

def distance(vector1, vector2):
    return size(vector1 - vector2)

def distances(array1, array2):
    ConvergenceCounter = 1
    keepGoing = True
    StartingCentroids = np.copy(centroids)
    while keepGoing:      
        #--------------Find The new means---------#
        np.linalg.norm(StartingCentroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :], axis=-1)
        t0 = StartingCentroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :]
        t1 = np.linalg.norm(t0, axis=-1)
        t2 = np.argmin(t1, axis=-1)
        cat = np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == 0], axis=0)
        #------Push the new means to a new array for comparison---------#
        CentroidMeans = []
        for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
            CentroidMeans.append(np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0))
        #--------Convert to a numpy array--------#
        NewMeans = np.asarray(CentroidMeans)
        #------Compare the New Means with the Starting Means------#
        if np.array_equal(NewMeans,StartingCentroids):
            print ('Convergence has been reached after {} moves'.format(ConvergenceCounter))
            print ('Starting Centroids:\n{}'.format(centroids))
            print ('Final Means:\n{}'.format(NewMeans))
            print ('Final Cluster assignments: {}'.format(t2))
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Cluster {}:\n'.format(x)), dataPoints[t2 == [x]]
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Size of Cluster {}:'.format(x)), len(dataPoints[t2 == [x]])
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            ConvergenceCounter  = ConvergenceCounter +1
            StartingCentroids =np.copy(NewMeans)
distances(centroids,dataPoints)
```

Using a smaller number for the `qty` variable seems to work without error.

Comment: where in the code is does the error occur? can you give us some code to replicate the error?

Comment: @putonspectacles The code is provided above. I am not sure where in the code the error occurs.